# Remove Border form Tikz SMart Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, diagrams, border

I want to remove border, set the box background to dark in the diagram below. I got no help from the document.

```
\begin{center}
\smartdiagramset{
set color list={blue,green,orange},
% border=none,
priority arrow width=2cm,
priority arrow height advance=2.25cm
}
\smartdiagram[priority descriptive diagram]{PGF,Ti\textit{k}Z,Smartdiagram}
\end{center}
```

Minimum EXample : https://www.overleaf.com/4876789zgmqhx#/14983098/

PLease help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `smartdiagram` documentation lists numerous options for `smartdiagramset`, but many of those options are specific to each diagram type. The following may be close to what you want.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\smartdiagramset{border color=none,uniform color list=blue for all items}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{text=white}
\smartdiagram[priority descriptive diagram]{
  Develop a document structure,
  Choose a document class,
  Select suitable packages,
  Setup the document preamble,
  Write your document,
  Finetune the layout}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: THanks a lot, ONe more question, How to change those ribbons in the arrow to small circles or bullets ?

Comment: Hi why does the upper side o each block have a greater contrast ? How can I remove that ?

Comment: @MichaelHert The position indicator along the ribbon is not trivial to change, so I'm afraid I can't help there. Regarding the contrast, the description block is defined to have a color gradient  going from white at the top to the item color at the bottom. You can change this, to black for example, by replacing the `\tikzset` line with the following: `\tikzset{text=white,description/.append style={top color=black}}`

Comment: Hi, how to make the arrow's color solid i.e again no contrast ?

Comment: @MichaelHert You can modify the fading settings on page 32 of the manual. For no transparency you can use `\tikzfading[name=priorityarrowfading, bottom color=transparent!0, top color=transparent!0]`. By the way, it's usually best to create separate posts for separate questions.